# With shiny selectize, avoid sorting of search results

Tags: r, shiny

In the reproducible shiny application below, the searchable selectize field reorders values by the *length of the character strings*.

[image]

If I type `1` to the search field, 'Gears' appears above 'Cylinders' because the string is *shorter*.
However, I want them in the original order, i.e., 11 above 12 above 13.

A thread in the [selectize repo](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/218) suggests to add something like `sortField: [{field: 'name', direction: 'asc'}]`, but I don't manage to add this in the shiny context. So adding `options = list(sortField = list(field = 'name', direction = 'asc'))` to `selectizeInput()` has no effect.

```
library(shiny)
choices <- c(
  "11 Cylinders" = "cyl",
  "12 Transmission" = "am",
  "13 Gears" = "gear"
)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectizeInput(
      "variable", 
      "Variable:", 
      choices
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
  }
)
```

Comment: @Shree, did you type in '1'?

Comment: @ismirsehregal Sorry, now I understand the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to have a look at @yonicd's updated answer (unfortunately, you will not be notified about it on SO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(shiny)

# must have named vector for selectize.js to pick up on the injection
choices <- c(
  "11 Cylinders" = "cyl",
  "12 Transmission" = "am",
  "13 Gears" = "gear"
)

# define JS to inject for options
##asceding order
sort_asc <- I("[{field: 'name', direction: 'asc'},{field: '$score'}]")

##decending order
sort_desc <- I("[{field: 'name', direction: 'desc'},{field: '$score'}]")

JS_opts <- list(create=TRUE,
                labelField =  'name',
                searchField = 'name',
                sortField = sort_asc
                )

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = "variable", 
      label = "Variable:", 
      choices = choices,
      options = JS_opts
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
  }
)
```

Comment: Please explain HOW your code snippet solves the OP's issue.

Comment: This results in a named list, which could be defined without `split` as `choices <- list(
  "11 Cylinders" = "cyl",
  "12 Transmission" = "am",
  "13 Gears" = "gear"
)` - But passing a named list instead of a named vector doesn't have any effect on the described behaviour.

Comment: You were correct the named list didn’t help. I updated the answer to give a reproducible solution.

Comment: After, your edit it works fine, thanks for sharing!